# Issue with Netmiko when using Nornir

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, netmiko

Iv recently been using Nornir with Netmiko to get some output from my devices.

When I run the following code:

```
    from nornir import InitNornir
    from nornir.core.filter import F
    from nornir_netmiko.tasks import netmiko_send_command, netmiko_send_config
    from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result
    
    nr = InitNornir(config_file="config.yml")
    test = nr.filter(platform="Cisco")
    result = test.run(netmiko_send_command, command_string="sh ver")
    print_result(result)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nornir/core/task.py", line 99, in start
    r = self.task(self, **self.params)
  File "/home/benanater/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nornir_netmiko/tasks/netmiko_send_command.py", line 26, in netmiko_send_command
    net_connect = task.host.get_connection(CONNECTION_NAME, task.nornir.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nornir/core/inventory.py", line 494, in get_connection
    self.open_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nornir/core/inventory.py", line 546, in open_connection
    conn_obj.open(
  File "/home/benanater/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nornir_netmiko/connections/netmiko.py", line 59, in open
    connection = ConnectHandler(**parameters)
  File "/home/benanater/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 321, in ConnectHandler
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported 'device_type' currently supported platforms are:
a10
```

Any help with why this error is being generated would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You set the platform equal to `Cisco` which is not mapped by the `netmiko_plugin` to any supported `device_type`. You should read the docs on [netmiko_plugin](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/a82ae784f4f1ef75e864ac972c088b8c963f77ff/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py#L109). The platform should be equivalent to `cisco_ios` or `cisco_ios_telnet`.

Answer (score 0):

inventory['options']['hosts_query] =  replace(replace(replace(replace(platform,'cisco-ios','ios'),'huawei_ce','huawei'),'cisco-nx-os','nxos'),'aruba','aruba_os') AS platform

Comment: you need  change the platform ios
test = nr.filter(platform="ios")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).